# Python list from Dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, nan

I have the following list:

```
db = [   DB_Field1 DB_Field2 DB_Field3
 4        1F1       1F2       1F3
 5        2F1       2F2       2F3
 6        3F1       3F2       3F3
 8        NaN       NaN       NaN
 11       NaN       NaN       NaN
 14       NaN       NaN       NaN,
    DB_Field4 DB_Field5
 4        1F4       1F5
 5        2F4       2F5
 6        3F4       3F5
 8        NaN       NaN
 11       NaN       NaN
 14       NaN       NaN,
    DB_Field6
 4        1F6
 5        2F6
 6        3F6
 8        NaN
 11       NaN
 14       NaN,
    DB_Field7 DB_Field7 DB_Field8 DB_Field9
 4        1F7       1F7       1F8       1F9
 5        2F7       2F7       2F8       2F9
 6        3F6       3F6       3F8       3F9
 8        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
 11       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
 14       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN,
    DB_Field10 DB_Field11 DB_Field12 DB_Field13 DB_Field13 DB_Field13  \
 4        1F10       1F11       1F12          1          1          1   
 5        2F10       2F11       2F12          2          2          2   
 6        3F10       3F11       3F12          3          3          3   
 8         NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
 11        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
 14        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   
 
    DB_Field13 DB_Field13  
 4           1          1  
 5           2          2  
 6           3          3  
 8         NaN        NaN  
 11        NaN        NaN  
 14        NaN        NaN  ]
```

I would like to save the above output as csv file and remove NaNs. How do I do that?

What I tried so far?

```
import xlsxwriter

with xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx') as workbook:
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row_num, data in enumerate(db):
        worksheet.write_row(row_num, 0, data)
```

This does not save the list properly. I get the following output:

[image: Output]

How can I save the entire list as csv and not just the column names?

Answer (score 1):

There are "to_csv" and "to_xlsx" functions in pandas. Just use them and they will remove NAN automatically.

ref:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Try [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
result=pd.concat(db,axis=1)
```

If you want to save this to a csv file then use [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```
result.dropna().to_csv('test.csv')
```

And if you want to save as excel then use [`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method:

```
result.dropna().to_excel('test.xlsx',index=False)
```